# ASP.NET bootstrap modal display

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, bootstrap-modal

There is a representation in the form of a table. If I click on the row name in the table, a modal window is displayed. Modal window with a form that is quite complex.

To display the modal window I use the following code:

```
$('#modal-container').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
    var url = button.attr("href");
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-content').load(url);
});    
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```

There are the following problems:

1. when repeated calls for some very short time, the contents of the last call are displayed - it is not so important
2. sometimes new content is not displayed at all, and the modal window contains information from the last call - it's very important

tell me, please, what could be the problem. I do not know much about JS

code where content is downloaded:

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade hidden-print" @*tabindex="-1" *@ role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

call from the action method

```
return PartialView("Details", projectECVM);
```

I suspect that the js runs faster than the razor generates the page.

Here I am forming a call for the action method:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ProjectVM)
    {
        <tr class="clickableProject" id="@item.Id" title="View BugReports for @item.ProjectName">
            <td id="Name">
                <a id="details-link" asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Project" asp-route-id="@item.Id" title="View details project @item.ProjectName" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-container">@Html.DisplayFor(it => item.ProjectName)</a>
            </td>
            <td id="Owner">
                <label class="clickableProject">@item.Owner</label>
            </td>
            <td id="TrelloBoardURL">
                <a id="trelloboard-link" href="@item.TrelloBoardURL" title="Go to TrelloBoard" target="_blank"><img src="~/images/trello-logo-blue.png" height="20" /></a>
            </td>
            <td id="Modification">
                <label class="clickableProject">@item.Modification</label>
            </td>
            <td id="By">
                <label class="clickableProject">@item.By</label>
            </td>
            <td id="DateTime">
                <label class="clickableProject">@item.EntryDateTime</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the content of the dialog box before loading new content:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(function () {
     $('#modal-container').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
         var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
         var url = button.attr("href");
         var modal = $(this);
         $(this).empty(); //adding this part before reloading it.
        modal.find('.modal-content').load(url);
     });    
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
     $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
     //$(this).empty(); //moved from shown
     $(this).removeData('modal');
 });
           if ($('#modal-container').text().trim().length > 0) {
                $('#modal-container').dialog('open');
            }
            else {
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: In this case, the old window is displayed for several milliseconds and immediately deleted, leaving only a dark background.The new window does not appear at all

Comment: I have updated the answer (moved it from shown to hidden

Comment: Do you set any properties of the dialog box somewhere  else. (I am assuming you are using a jquery dialog box)

Comment: The first call works fine, the second one does not show anything anymore

Comment: I'm using the bootstrap dialog box

Comment: Updated it again. Document.ready wait for page load to complete.

Comment: same problem.
string:  $(this).empty(); - in $('#modal-container').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event)  immediately hides the window. Without it, everything works as it was (with the same problems)